# Export data from Elastic search to local Docker container

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I am trying to create a local elastic search docker container with data to be populated from my dev environment elastic search.

I found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticdump) npm plugin `elasticdump` which can do this job. So I create a container [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/javatechy/elasticsearch_dump/) from elastic search 6.2.4 image

and installed node and elastdump npm plugin in my image.

then created create a Docker file to dump the data from my dev server after container is up:

```
FROM javatechy/elasticsearch_dump:1.0
CMD elasticdump  --input=http://dev.server.com:9200/search-log-index --output=http://127.0.0.1:9200/search-log-index  --type=data
CMD elasticdump  --input=http://dev.server.com:9200/user-index --output=http://127.0.0.1:9200/user-index  --type=data
```

When I built and run this image.  I got this error:

```
deepak:~/projects/dock-es$ docker build -t myimage .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  8.704kB
Step 1/6 : FROM javatechy/elasticsearch_dump:1.0
 ---> 51c31a5c6d13
Step 2/6 : MAINTAINER Javatechy
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5d9799b6b075
Step 3/6 : CMD elasticdump  --input=http://dev.server.com:9200/search-l
.........
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 236c55625a6d
Successfully built 42000b42292b
Successfully tagged myimage:latest

deepak:~/projects/dock-es$ docker run -it myimage
Tue, 05 Jun 2018 11:12:29 GMT | starting dump
Tue, 05 Jun 2018 11:12:30 GMT | got 100 objects from source elasticsearch (offset: 0)
Tue, 05 Jun 2018 11:12:30 GMT | Error Emitted => connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200
Tue, 05 Jun 2018 11:12:30 GMT | Total Writes: 0
Tue, 05 Jun 2018 11:12:30 GMT | dump ended with error (set phase)  => Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200
```

Why am I getting this error on `connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200` ?

Answer (score 0):

You tried to index data to `127.0.0.1:9200`, but your elasticsearch didn't start at this moment. So you have to start your ES in container before executing elasticdump command.

Comment: Is there a way to execute a script in container after it is up?

Comment: @DeepakKumar Yes you can do that by using exec docker command
                                         
**docker container exec -it <container_name_or_id> <CMD>**

Comment: @sarathkumar is it possible with docker run command itself.  I don't want my user to execute 2 commands?

Comment: you can change the entry point to a script that runs ES, and then runs some command, `elasticdump` in your case

Comment: @DeepakKumar it is possible to do that but the command CMD will be overwritten. if you are ok with this the add your command just after the image name. Thanks !!!

Comment: @DeepakKumar insted you can include these commands in a shell like file and you include them like a execute expression in CMD command in the docker file. like **CMD ./setup.sh;**. Remember that the command included in the CMD command will execute every time a new container was created.

Comment: @sarathkumar I tried it earlier but didn't work. I got the same error in this case as well